# Informix - Select from partition

Tags: sql, informix, database-partitioning

I am trying to perform a select on a very large table with no applicable indexes in Informix.  Unfortunately it is not possible to add an applicable index by the time this project needs to be finished - there are strict procedures in place for database changes and it would take too long to get the required sign off in my organization.

The table is fragmented, and I have selected from particular partitions in Oracle databases before.  Is there any way to specify the fragment in a `SELECT` query?

Comment: Can you predict how many results your query will return?.. If this a one-time ad-hoc query, can you clone the table and add the indexes to support the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only indirectly...

If your search criteria identify the rows to be selected in part based on the expression(s) used in the partitioning, then Informix will perform 'fragment elimination' to avoid scanning partitions (fragments) that cannot possibly contribute to the answer.  If you have round robin partitioning, then no fragment elimination is possible.  If you have expression or interval fragmentation, then you can benefit from fragment elimination.  (Because fragment elimination is a big win on performance, it is done whenever possible.)

Ultimately, though, if you can't put the proper indexes in place, the query performance will probably be slow as it may well require table scans and those can be slower than indexed access operations.  That said, sometimes a table scan is the quickest way to process a query.  It just isn't often the case.

Comment: Thanks Johnathan.  I assume that the table is using round robin partitioning because the fragments are numbered (i.e. tablename01, tablename02, etc.).  Do you know how I would check?

Comment: The info is in the system catalog, but I'd have to look to see where.  Likely something like 'sysfragments'.

Comment: I confirmed that it's recorded in the sysfragments.strategy column.  Turns out that this table is round robin partitioned.  The documentation for this table is at http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v117/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.sqlr.doc%2Fids_sqr_040.htm

Answer (score 0):

How to determine if the table is using round robin fragmentation? Two ways:

One easy way is to get the schema of the table/index using dbschema

```
UNIXprompt> dbschema -d <db name> -ss -t <table name>
```

if you see the words "round robin" in the table creation DDL, then you'll know.

The other one, query the SMI:

```
database <db name>;
select unique(strategy) from sysfragments
 where fragtype = 'T'  
   and tabid = (select tabid from systables where tabname = '<table name>';
```

Here is the value key for the strategy column:
R = Round-robin fragmentation strategy
E = Expression-based fragmentation strategy
I = IN DBSPACE clause specifies a specific location as part of fragmentation strategy
T = Table-based fragmentation strategy
H = Table is a subtable witin a table hierarchy (IDS), or Hash-based fragmentation strategy (XPS).

Last but not least, I work with XLDBs (largest table so far is 1.5k wide, 600+ columns, 60 billion recs, yes, billion), and indexing **DOES MAKE A HUGE** difference, as in seconds vs hours (granted, I had ≈100 vCPUs dedicated to my database server) so I'd suggest you make the petition to your Change Control council and create your index, when you get permission to do it, just make sure you use the "online" clause, determine your correct fillfactor and don't forget to update statistics (use Art's dostat).

My 2 cents...